# Solderless Board IC decoder 4511

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I'm new to circuits, I tried following this link http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_6.html to create a 7 segment decoder. I have set up everything on a solderless board, but I have no clue what I'm missing because whenever I press any of the 4 switches or combine any, it lights up all the LEDs.

What am I missing here? Please point me to the right direction. Here's a screen shot of my solderless board:

[image]

Comment: As per comments on your previous question breadboard photos are very hard to follow. Can you attempt to put together a schematic of how at least you think it's connected? The way the switches are connected still looks dodgy to me, but it's hard to make out.

Comment: Like PeterJ says. And what happens if you don't press any button?

Comment: Apart from the pull-downs mentioned below are pins 8 (ground) and 16 (Vdd / power) connected to anything? I can't see how they are and you'll get all sorts of bizarre behaviour if not.

Comment: Guy's i was able to connect everything except the latch or pin5 but all i'm getting is a display of zero when connected with battery, what could be wrong?

Comment: The question was better with at least a photo. Would even be better with the schematic. -1 for actually *decreasing* the question quality.

Comment: Rolled back the image removal. Seriously, removing that makes your question completely unanswerable.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really make out how your circuit is connected from the photo. One thing I can make out is that A3 (pin 6) and A0 (pin 7) and 0V - pin 8 don't seem to be connected so I'm surprised anything works.

As regards a schematic your circuit should be something like this;

[image]

I suspect you haven't got pull down resistors so your inputs are floating high. Also make sure BI (Blank Input - pin 4) and LT (Lamp Test - pin 3) are connected to +V.

Pin 5 is the STROBE input which you can use to latch the data by taking it LOW momentarily.

Comment: Sorry beginner here. i'm not sure if i got it right, is my illustration correct? the BCD 4511 have total of 16 pins, 8 on top and 8 below, is my illustration labeling correct? i don't know what goes on the extra pin i labeled question mark. Can you please tell me if my illustration is correct? Thanks here's a screen shot http://s11.postimg.org/ymci12isz/IMG_0160_1.jpg

Comment: @user27586 No - your connections are all wrong. I've added the pinout for the chip to my answer. Connect pins 3 (LT),4(BI) and 16 (Vdd) to +V, pin 8(Vss) to 0V. Your 4 (BCD) inputs to pins 7 (A),2(B),4(C) and 6(D).  On the output side connect pin 13 to segment a, 12 to b, 11 to c, 10 to d, 9 to e, 15 to f and 14 to g through a 470R resistor. Don't apologize for being a beginner - we were all beginners at one time.

Comment: It looks like you have confused the schematic symbol for the real world pins... They are not the same and  unless it's pointed out how would you know? Try again it might have survived.

Comment: is pin 8 oV connected to GND?

Comment: Guy's i was able to connect everything except the latch or pin5 but all i'm getting is a display of zero when connected with battery, what could be wrong? screenshot http://s17.postimg.org/43mx2cam7/IMG_0166_1.jpg ?

Comment: @user27586 connect pin 5 (latch) to 0V

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could include a schematic of your design. At first glance it looks as though you do not have pull-up / pull-down resistors on your push buttons. Since you have connected one side of the push buttons to ground you would need to connect pull-up resistors to the other side of the push button. This will put a positive voltage on the input to the 4511 when the push button is open. Without the pull-up resistor the input on the 4511 is floating when the push button is open.

Comment: Sorry beginner here. i'm not sure if i got it right, is my illustration correct? the BCD 4511 have total of 16 pins, 8 on top and 8 below, is my illustration labeling correct? i don't know what goes on the extra pin i labeled question mark. Can you please tell me if my illustration is correct? Thanks here's a screen shot http://s11.postimg.org/ymci12isz/IMG_0160_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You say you've connected all the pins except the latch (which is pin 5).

Why do you think you can leave pin 5 unconnected?

The latch pin (pin 5) **has to be pulled low** to transfer the value on the binary inputs to the display.

Basically, you apply the binary word you want to display, *set the latch input low (if it wasn't already)*, and the binary work is **latched** into the IC, and displayed on the connected LED display.

If you then set the latch input high, the binary word is stored into the IC, and changing the inputs will not cause the outputs to change.

Since you have left the input *floating*, it has probably drifted up to Vcc, and is preventing your inputs from having any effect. You need to hard-wire it to ground.