# 7 Segment display Stuck on number 0

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I'm new to circuits and am trying to make a 7 segment display decoder with a 4511. My display is stuck on zero, nothing happens when I press any of the switches, what could be wrong? Here is a photo:

[image]

Pin 5 or latch is not connected to anything does that make a difference? Do we have to connect it? If yes where?

Comment: FOR. THE. THIRD. TIME... SCHEMATIC.

Comment: i followed this schematic http://s13.postimg.org/6gblbpox3/Uo7_Xw.png sorry :(

Comment: More than the third time: 1. ["The first thing I'd suggest is to make a schematic."](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79252/2028), 2. ["It's hard to say without a schematic..."](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/79256/2028), 3. ["we need to see a wiring diagram ... that shows how you believe you have the display and switches connected."](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/79255/2028), 4. ["Can you attempt to put together a schematic of how at least you think it's connected?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79656/2028)...

Comment: And 5. ["It would be helpful if you could include a schematic of your design."](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/79660/2028). @user27586, Do you think maybe schematics are important? We're not trying to be cranky, but you have to "help us help you."

Comment: i did follow the above input, my switches works fine. When i hook up the battery it's stuck on zero, i don't have anything on strobe/latch as i'm really confused about the concept of HI and LOW? i can't find any tutorial video for this :(

Comment: I just rolled back your last edit - I'm not sure what you were trying to do but it removed most of the question.

Comment: @user27586 Wait a second, you need a *tutorial video* for high and low?

Comment: @user27586 Why do you keep removing the images/schematic in your question?

Comment: If you would (a) stick to [your original question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79656/14004), editing it as needed, and (b) not edit relevant parts, such as schematic and image, out of the question repeatedly, yeah... that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to the [Datasheet](http://www.uib.es/depart/dfs/GTE/staff/jfont/InstrETT/hef4511b.pdf) to have a good explanation.

> When EL is LOW, the state of the segment outputs (Oa to
>   Og) is determined by the data on DA to DD.
>   When EL goes HIGH, the last data present on DA to
>   DD are stored in the latches and the segment outputs
>   remain stable. When LT is LOW, all the segment outputs
>   are HIGH independent of all other input conditions. With
>   LT HIGH, a LOW on BI forces all segment outputs LOW.
>   The inputs LT and BI do not affect the latch circuit.

The data on the FUNCTION TABLE on page 4 is also very useful. From reading that:

- So you should keep EL (pin5) LOW, if you switch it to HIGH it will hold the last value.
- Also keep BI (pin4) and LT (pin 3) in a HIGH state.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm  new to circuits, when does  LT becomes low or LT is High?

Comment: LOW => connected to GND; HIGH => connected to VCC. You want to connect all inputs (according to the datasheet), especially when you are troubleshooting.